# How to test circuit with AC mains voltage?

Tags: ac

From my experience, testing circuits with a lab bench power supply is great because it protects the circuit and itself from over current or short circuit when anything goes wrong.

I wonder how I can do that with AC main voltage (230 V).

My circuit is a 230 V BLDC driver using a diode bridge to rectify 230 V AC to 325 V DC (Approximately) then using microcontroller and IGBT to drive the motor.

When something goes wrong it might really dangerous.

What should I do?

These are some risk of my circuit that I think of.

1. High voltage jumps across some gap.
2. Shoot through via half bridge (short circuit)
3. Some controller error might cause over current (fault current controller)

Comment: Use Inverse Logic and think how many ways can I cause a disaster, then avoid those.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I update my question. these reason can mad my circuit doom, still can't figure it out how to avoid it.

Comment: You cannot rectify 230V AC to 230V DC with a bus reservoir capacitor needed by a BLDC controller. If you don't already know that, MathKeepsMeBusy's answer is quite appropriate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I will update answer for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My circuit is 230 V BLDC driver using diode bridge to rectify 230 V AC to 230 V DC ...

No. The DC link voltage will be \$ 230 \sqrt 2 \ \text V \$.

> When something go wrong it might really dangerous what should I do?

1. Use an isolation transformer.
2. Connect an incandescent lamp in series between the transformer supply and your test circuit. The lamp will allow the DC bus to charge up when the BLDC drive is switched off and will cause the voltage to drop when running. If a short-circuit should occur the lamp will go to full brightness.
   You'll need to work out what lamp wattage you need to allow sufficient current to flow to run the motor unloaded. Your next problem will be finding the lamp.
3. Add a circuit breaker on the isolated side of the transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFPZn8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Possible test layout.*

LAMP1 acts as a current limiter. Open SW1 while powering up and on initial unloaded trials. When you're happy that nothing bad is happening and the lamp doesn't glow full brightness then you can close the switch. Many variable frequency supplies use a similar arrangement to limit the power-on surge current due to the discharged capacitor as this might damage the rectifier. They'll use a resistor and a relay rather than a lamp and switch.

XMFR1 isolates the L + N so now you can ground your DC- and safely attach the scope earth clip there. The DC LINK+ will be dangerous. Take care.

Comment: How  isolation transformer help to safe me or my circuit or my Main AC line? When AC is isolated what about grounding?

Comment: You're going to have to do some research on that. There are plenty of questions and answers on the topic on this site. Search for "isolation transformer testing". The isolation allows you to at least ground the DC- which you can't do on a direct mains supply.

Comment: Ok that really help me, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

At least using an isolation transformer 230V/230V. By the way, the rectified voltage is something approx. 325VDC and not 230VDC. If you would like to use a scope, then a HV differential probe is also a good option. Yet another good option would be using a HV DC power supply with current limit setpoint.

Comment: And use ground fault protection will be good if no grounded neutral.

Comment: 200V on 'standard' probes is usually asking for troubles; you'll have 20V on the scope but beware for spikes and transients. Even CAT II for a low end scope can be damaging

Answer (score 1):

> Note these are some risk of my circuit that I think of.

> High voltage jump across some gap.

With clean dry surfaces expect arc to sharp edges at 1kV/mm and use a 3:1 safety factor

> Shoot through via half bridge (Short circuit)

This requires a design deadtime for a known reactive delay and load Q. However deadtime also causes flyback.  Design appropriate means of measuring shoot thru current or device temperature to increase deadtime or shut down and latch gates.

> Some controller error might cause over current (fault current controller)

Over-current causes thermal rise. Use both current sense and temp sense for OCP and OTP.

Comment: The shoot through can occur when one of IGBT die and result in short circuit right?

Comment: Using fast OCP ought to crowbar gate drive unless stored Joules exceeds IGBT surge spec

Answer (score 1):

An isolation transformer with a relatively small core will limit the maximum energy available to the circuit.  For example, a 100 W transformer would limit the short circuit current to approx 1 A (2 x the core rating).  A fast-acting magnetic circuit breaker also will limit the damage caused by a circuit error.

If you cannot find an isolation transformer that is small enough, use two "normal" low voltage transformers back-to-back.  For example, two small power transformers with 12 V / 1 A secondaries will limit the circuit power to approx 12 W.  Connect the two secondaries together and connect one primary to the AC source.  The other primary now will be an AC source at line voltage level, but limited to approx 0.05 A.  As the load current increases above this, the output voltage will decrease.

Comment: Ok this help me understand how it work thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

> when something go wrong it might really dangerous what should I do?

If you are unsure what you should be doing with 230V AC, then you should not be doing experiments with 230V AC. Period.

In the US, accidental electrocution is the 6th leading cause of work-related deaths.

Comment: So you mean there are no instrument or tool or some protection circuit to make my life safer?

Comment: I mean that if you haven't been properly trained, you could potentially kill yourself. An answer on the internet is not a suitable substitute for such training. Any advice we give you may give you a false sense of safety.

Comment: Hmm I think I know how dangerous of AC. at least I can power my circuit with long wire switch to avoid touching any ac wire but I don't think it safe enought when compare to lab bench power supply testing DC circuit.

Comment: But if you knew how to handle 230VAC properly, you wouldn't be asking for advice on the internet.

Comment: The question isn't about personal safety but bringing it up in an answer is fine. The question is about circuit protection and you haven't addressed this at all. Adding "period" after a period always seems strange and suggests that you are not open to discussion on the matter (so why am I trying?).

Comment: OP: "when something go wrong it might really dangerous what should I do?", @Transistor: "The question isn't about personal safety"

Comment: I don't know what can happen when my circuit go wrong, My circuit might broken and I lose a lot of money to make the new one or something are on fire or my AC wire on fire or something explode. what ever my it terrible so plese help me to avoid these risk.

Comment: @Mlab - it is always wisdom to preserve life over property. You must not let go of the warning while you seek knowledge, and appreciate **both** the warning of wisdom along with the knowledge. Penalize not the wise person having good judgement! Value your life! You can always buy it again, or do without. Once you're dead, then you really have no recourse!

Comment: @Mlab - Suggest you find a mentor in your area.